# fork() call printing more times than expected

Tags: c, fork

The code looks something like this

```
int main() {
    printf("Starting process id is %d\t", getpid());
    if (fork() == 0) {
         fork();
     } else {
         fork();
         fork();
         exit(0);
     }
     printf("%d\t", getpid());
}
```

For the most part the outputs behave as expected where tracing. That is if we start with id `n` we get `n+1` and `n+5` being printed. However when I print the starting process id it gets printed 5 times and I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated

Output from a sample run looks like this

> Starting process id is 27252  pc@pc-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$
> Starting porcess id is 27252  Starting porcess id is 27252    Starting
> porcess id is 27252   27253   Starting porcess id is 27252    Starting
> process id is 27252   27257

However I would have expected to see

> Staring process id is 27252 27253 27257

Comment: What output do you get, and what sort of output did you expect?

Comment: Fork/line buffering multi-dupe:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial `printf` doesn't end in a newline, and by default `stdout` connected to a terminal is line buffered. Thus, when you `fork`, the `stdout` buffer isn't empty, and when flushed by each child process on `exit`, it flushes the same data left in the buffer that it inherited.

To fix, do the following:

1. `fflush(stdout)` before `fork`ing
2. Exit the forked child processes with [`_exit`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit), not `exit` (this can prevent buffers from being flushed, though it's implementation dependent so you can't make guarantees, but it also blocks `atexit` functions from being executed in the child process, which is usually the desired behavior)
3. As an optional alternative or complement to #1, you can use [`tcflush`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcflush) to clear the buffered output prior to `_exit`-ing.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly when I call printf() anything I try to print while my program is running is saved in a buffer and then when the program terminates the buffer is printed to stdout?

Comment: @Mitchel0022: The usual rules are that `stderr` is unbuffered, `stdout` is line buffered when connected to a terminal (so it flushes the buffer when it sees a newline in output or the underlying buffer fills, whichever comes first), and `stdout` connected to anything else, and all other opened handles, are block buffered (so they flush when the buffer fills, the size of the buffer being implementation defined). The buffer is also flushed when the handle is closed (which happens implicitly on program exit), which is why all your children are printing.

Comment: Ahh, replacing the `\t` with a `\n` does force it to clear the buffer. Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

It's because `printf` is buffering your output, not immediately flushing it to the device.

So, when you fork, the copy of the process *also* has that information buffered and *each* process will output the full string.

You should try calling `fflush(stdout)` (and possibly `fsync(fileno(stdout))` depending on your platform) before each fork.